# how to make a correct bootable usb of a linux distro?

Tags: linux, iso-image, bootable-media, dd, unetbootin

well I have been installing different distros of linux from by usb from time to time. And I always followed same method which until today stopped working for me.

So I use to format my usb with gparted into fat32 filesystem.

after that i will download the iso image of the linux distro i want to install (usually ubuntu)

open unetbootin and give it the location of my iso image on my hard-disk and location where my usb is (name of port).

unetbootin will usually do the trick for me and i can install the operation system on the computer by booting from that usb.

but today I tried this process several times and failed. Every distro gives almost same error.

- can not mount on file-system.
- (root) file system not defined.

other way I find on searching online was to use dd instead of unetbootin that too did not worked mostly it gives me an error that says isolinux.bin missing.

I even tried making a bootable usb using these guidelines
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows 
that too also did not worked.

- and now the worst I tried fedore which installed perfectly and now will not boot from my hard disk (give some errors on booting first time) 
  I tried installing fedora with unetbootin (as I use to do)
  screenshot --> [image]

anyone can guide me how to make a live usb correctly? or tell me how to fix this error on fedora?

Thanks

Comment: Try formatting the disk as VFAT, not FAT32.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into same issue once.

Issue was that my FEDORA iso was corrupted.

Download Fedora again and make sure to see checksum